# Racket/Scheme - Applying a function to each element in a list of lists

Tags: recursion, scheme, set-theory

I am a physics major who is taking a math class with programming (I enrolled for the math), but I have never coded in any language before, so everything about Racket is completely new to me.  The goal of the class so far is to take set-related functions and convert them to Racket programs.  One of these functions is to take a list of lists and remove the first item of each element:

f({(0, 1, 0), (1, 0, 0), (1, 1, 1)...} = {(1, 0), (0, 0), (1, 1)...}

I've gotten this as a procedure so far:

```
(define (procA set)
  (cond
    ((null? set) '())
    ((rest (first set)))
    ((procA (rest set)))))
```

When I run the program, it comes back with the proper function applied, but only with the first element, like how

```
(procA '((0 1 0) (1 0 0) (1 1 1)))
```

comes back to be '(1 0).  Is it some sort of "map" function, or something completely different?  I thought the last line would take care of the rest of the list, but it didn't.

Comment: Yes, it's supposed to be the same as `(map rest set)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @uselpa commented, it is the same as `map rest`. If you want to implement it, you need to use recursion and `cons` together the resulting list.

The most straight-forward approach, I think, is to use `if` to find the base case of the empty list:

```
(define (procB set)
  (if (null? set)
      '()
      (cons (rest (first set)) (procB (rest set)))))
```

If you want to use `cond`, the same can be written as

```
(define (procC set)
  (cond
    ((null? set) '())
    (else (cons (rest (first set)) (procC (rest set))))))
```

(where the `else` is not necessary in this case: if left out it will also be the "test expression without body" case described below. NB I only mean deleting the word `else`, not the expression following it.)

That is, the only thing missing from your code was the `cons`. In your code, the last statement (with the recursion) will never be executed, as `cond` chooses the first test-expression that is true (and `(rest non-empty-list)` is a "truthy" value. A similar example:

```
> (cond 
    ((= 1 2) 0)
    ((+ 3 4))
    ((+ 5 6)))
7
```

where the first test-expression is false, so it goes on to the second, which is true, and as it has no body, the result of the test expression becomes the result of the `cond`. The third test-expression is never executed.

Comment: Thank you so much!  It seems so simple when I look at the answer.  I'll try the rest of the problems using this approach.

Comment: Now I am making a function that replaces the first element of each list with 1 (i.e.: f(0, 0, 1) = (1, 0, 1)).  Everything looks the same as the first one, but instead of (rest (first set)) I have ((number? (first (first set))) (cons 1 (rest (first set)))).  I think this is right, but I have an error "application: not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
  given: #t"

Comment: Are you working from the "How To Design Programs" textbook? It gives really solid concrete steps in solving problems like this. Specifically, you're working on section 10.1, "Functions that produce lists": http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/HtDP2e/part_two.html#%28part._sec~3alist-produce%29

Comment: I should mention: the "How To Design Programs" textbook is written by the Racket team. In many ways, Racket is specifically designed to work with this text.

Comment: @CompNoob,  make the follow-up a new question so you can post the complete procedure and problem. It gets a bit cryptic as a comment.  In general,  try to divide and conquer: try out the parts in the REPL before attempting to write the entire procedure.

Comment: *problem --> question

Answer (score -1):

```
(define (exclude list)
  (if (empty? list) '""
  (let ((r (rest list)) (f (rest (first list))))
   (~a f (exclude r))

)))
(exclude '( (3 4 5) ( 6 7 8) ( 9 10 11)))

;(4 5)(7 8)(10 11)
```